# Copy distinct string by by matching items that meet a criterion

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I need to copy a value when two criteria are met in two tables.

Table A contains name of District, name of municipality, and code of municipality.

Table B contains name of district, code of municipality and administrative unit of municipality.

In Table A, there are 50 districts and 40 municipalities (200 rows).

But Table B contains data of 50 districts, 40 municipalities and 15 administrative unit of municipalities (3000 rows).

My problem: copy name of municipality in Table B, when name of district and code municipality match in Table A and Table B to all administrative units of Table B.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First insert a new column before Name of District in Table A and put as Header Name of District & Code of municipality and write the following in it
 `=B2 & D2`   to concatenate in the same cell Name of District (in B) & Code of municipality (in D).
Do the same with Table B insert a new column in A and write
`=B2 & C2`
in B you have Name of District and in C you have Code of Municipality.
in Table B under Name of Municipality write:
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'Table A'!$A$2:$D$4,3,FALSE),"")`
where `'Table A'!$A$2:$D$4` is your Data in Table A (in column A you should have the combination Name of District & Code of municipality, and in column C Name of Municipality and you can drag it for all rows, when you finish insert a new column and copy the result and paste special values in the new column.

Comment: Thanks @SuperSam ! This is exactly what we are looking for. Unfortunately, when dragging formula beyound first 30 rows did not work. Any suggestion??

Comment: did you check the references can you upload a screen shot

Comment: What are the references in Table B and in Table A when you drag you have to keep the array fix